# Is it bad to declare and use controls at a local level?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

```
Panel Pan_TitlePanel = new Panel()
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
    Height = SETTINGS.TITLEPANELHEIGHT,
    BackColor = SETTINGS.TITLEPANELCOLOR
};
Pan_TitlePanel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(TitlePanel_MouseDown);
Pan_TitlePanel.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(TitlePanel_MouseUp);
Pan_TitlePanel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(TitlePanel_MouseMove);
this.Controls.Add(Pan_TitlePanel);
```

I've used this code within a form initialiser. As you can see the declaration of the variable Pan_TitlePanel is within the function, thus making it local.

Is this bad practise, especially when the panel has events that it triggers. I do not need to reference it at any other point in my code, so was just curious if this is bad, or perfectly fine.

Comment: Not really.  You can shorten your event declarations to just `Pan_TitlePanel.MouseDown += TitlePanel_MouseDown;` etc.

Comment: This is quite commonly used. If your handlers are not that complex (just for readability), you can substitute the standard handler delegate with a Lambda (as shown in kennyzx answer).  The Control is added to a Container's controls collection: its reference will persist.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see there is a problem with this, it works perfectly this way.

It will not be GC’ed even after it is “out of scope” since it is always referenced by the form.

And you can always access it from one of the three event handlers, thru the sender object, for example, when you want to remove it from the form.

You can further shorten your code by replacing the event handlers with anonymous methods.

```
Pan_TitlePanel.MouseDown += (sender, args) => { /* put your logic here */};
```

Comment: @LarsTech oh yes. That is why they say never write code on iPhone.